# 'is not within a known GOPATH/src' error on dep init

Tags: go

When I run `dep init` in project folder, the error occurs:

> init failed: unable to detect the containing GOPATH: D:\projects\foo is not within a known GOPATH/src

My projects are located on another drive and not `%GOPATH%/src` (i.e.  `%USERPROFILE%\go\src`).

It's a known error but it's unclear what is the solution.

How can I use `dep` without moving Go projects to `%GOPATH%/src`?

Comment: Go projects must be in `GOPATH` in order to use the go tools.

Comment: You [write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) inside the `GOPATH/src`.

Comment: Why are you fighting the tools?

Comment: Basic questions tend to be heavily downvoted these days, even properly asked ones (and not only mine). Seems like answering same newbie questions again and again made the communities too toxic and snobbish. @Flimzy I didn't embrace them yet and it's still hard to believe that tools are that restricting. It isn't like that with other package managers I have experience with.

Comment: This isn't being downvoted for being basic. Rather, it's being downvoted for not showing research effort. We get frequent questions about people foolishly trying to fight the Go tools for no reason.

Comment: @Flimzy IMO every single basic question shows a lack of research because it can be solved by studying some read. It wasn't obvious for me if it's `dep` or Go requirement, I'm currently focused on code rather than infrastructure and didn't have a chance to know that GOPATH can contain multiple paths. Using a drive of my choice to store some projects can hardly be considered 'no reason'. From my understanding, the solution in my case is to add `D:\projects` to GOPATH, not to move them to current one. IMO, this is more like 'figuring out the right solution', not 'fighting the tools'.

Comment: @estus GOPATH should not contain multiple paths, just move your project to `GOPATH/src`.

Comment: @mkopriva Why is that? The documentation suggests this as an option. And I'd prefer to keep D:\projects for my own projects, not for every Go app that will be built on this system.

Comment: @estus I don't think the documentation says that, can you please point me to it.

Comment: @mkopriva: GOPATH takes a path separator, and it's perfectly valid to contain multiple values, just like PATH. https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable. This is however not highly recommended, as it tends to cause more confusion than it's worth, but it is there for advanced usage.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, I thought this whole time it actually wasn't allowed, not just recommended against. Ignore my previous comment estus.

Comment: I don't think this question is basic to a fault. You guys say don't fight the tools, but how much sense does it make have all your go code in one location, albeit seperated by folders? My practice has been to have a project folder holding a few repos of microservices like UI & backend systems. Intuitively it doesn't make sense for me to have go code in the GOPATH/src while all the other code exists outside GOPATH. You say don't fight the tools, I say you are getting forced to have this habit driven by Go.

Comment: I recommend reading up on “Go modules” for the modern solution to this problem.

Comment: What @Wildcard wrote. Go modules solves this problem now and has quickly become the defacto standard for new Go projects:

https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go makes this choice so that there is nothing like a CLASSPATH (ie: Java) to deal with.  You specify a $GOPATH that has a consistent src tree inside of it.  If your repo makes references to particular git commits (rather than the ones checked out into $GOPATH/src/github.com/$githubUser/$githubProjectName), then those will be in the ./vendor directory of your project.

If you have a different Go project that uses a completely different set of checkouts, due to versioning issues, then you can have multiple $GOPATH values to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks. Is it safe to assume that GOPATH paths are completely independent, and there's no chance that a project located at one path will accidentally use packages from another path?

Comment: Correct.  If you work on two completely different projects that you switch between, and have no dependencies on each other, then you want two independent GOPATH variables.  Before vendoring was a thing, you really needed to do this to deal with versioning.  Now, you mostly only do "go get" on toplevel projects and vendor everything that they depend on.

Comment: wasn't GOPATH obsolete thing after go `dep`  was released? I heard you no longer need to set GOPATH

Comment: people are migrating to modules, but there is way more to a real build than just the go compiler.  chances are, if you do a large go program, you still use GOROOT and GOPATH.  Code is often still structured to do checkouts into $GOPATH/src/${gitsite}/${authoraccount}/${project}.

Comment: this is particularly true (still using GOPATH) if you have two repos, where you are actively working on BOTH of them at the same time.

Comment: and it still stands that generally, your dependents are stable, and in ./vendor.  But you might reference devs that you are actually working on, in which case, GOPATH gives you some structure so that you can write things like bash scripts.  etc: reference a test TLS cert that exists under a repo, or a yaml file.

Comment: Downvoted because while the answer explained the problem it did not provide a direct solution. Turgut Kalfaoglu's answer did instead.

Answer (score 10):

> How can I use dep without moving Go projects to %GOPATH%/src?

Not at all.

Comment: @IvanAracki With Go modules there is no need for dep anymore, so what is your comment addressing?

Comment: projects could be easily moved outside of $GOPATH

Comment: Many many softlinks, and wrapper scripts.  That's how I had to do it in order to keep all my source in the correct place rather than split the go part into another location.

Answer (score 7):

Go projects require that your project is within its path..
So first do a 
`$ go env`
to find out where that is. Lets say it says **/home/turgut/go**
move the project that you downloaded that needs the dep to:
**/home/turgut/go/src/myproject**
then `cd /home/turgut/go/src/myproject`
and try the 
`dep ensure`
command now.

Comment: I understand that, the question was how to avoid keeping source files in unwanted location.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I was the only one that explained how to solve the problem rather than just saying why you can't keep them in the unwanted location.

Answer (score 6):

what does `go env` command say your **GOPATH** is? Set GOPATH for your environment as per this [doc](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH)

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps here https://deployer.org/docs/7.x/installation

you can use this command `vendor/bin/dep init` instead of `dep init`